# Hide Product based on the selected country woocommerce - PBC Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using PBC (price based on country)[Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-price-based-on-countries/) to have different prices for different countries manually. As of now its showing "read more" at shop page if price is not set for particular product for a particular country while creating product. 
i would like to hide all products if product with text "read more" or with no price are created for particular country & when woocommerce country is selected from drop down widget at homepage by the customer if product is not available in his selected country.

I have tried following solution with different combinations:

```js
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'react2wp_hide_products_without_price' );
function react2wp_hide_products_without_price( $q ){
   $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
   $meta_query[] = array(
      'key'       => '_Brazil_regular_price' ,
      'value'     => '',
      'compare'   => '!='
   );
 
   $meta_query[] = array(
      'key'       => '_Cannada_price' ,
      'value'     => '',
      'compare'   => '!='
   );

   $meta_query[] = array(
      'key'       => '_price' ,
      'value'     => '',
      'compare'   => '!='
   );
   $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

Above query doesn't seems to be working properly.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this?

Comment: Not so far. but i am not presently working on it.